# Trouble with my SQL join/group by/cursor question

Tags: sql-server

I've made database design for a small CRM system. It comprises of Companies and Meetings (amongst others).

Companies has the fields:
ID (primary, auto_inc)
Name (text)

Meetings has the fields:
ID (primary, auto_inc)
CompanyId (link to Companies.ID)
WhenTime (datetime, to store when the meeting was)
Notes (text about the meeting)

What I want to accomplish is a query that gives me a list of all Companies (all fields in the table), AND the WhenTime and Notes of the latest meeting with that company (latest is max(WhenTime), and if there is none, a NULL will do fine).

I think I can solve this with cursors, but I'm afraid of speed.

I've tried several Group By formulations, but I fear I lack the finesse required.

My last attempt was this:

```
select Companies.ID, Companies.name, mts.whentime, mts.notes
from Companies
left outer join (
    select top(1) *
    from Meetings
    order by [whentime] desc
) mts
on Companies.ID = mts.companyID
order by Companies.name asc
```

but this code only takes one tuple from Meetings, not one per company in the join, so it's no good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to list all companies, or only those which have had at least one meeting?

Comment: all companies, with the latest meeting time and stuff if available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select Companies.ID, Companies.name, mts.whentime, mts.notes
from Companies
cross apply 
(
    select top(1) *
    from Meetings
    where Companies.ID = Meetings.companyID
    order by [whentime] desc
) mts
order by Companies.name asc;
```

Comment: If you want to include companies that have never had a meeting, use OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by creating a view of the latest meetings as I find creating views makes complex queries easier to read and maintain and can introduce an element of reusability (if done right).

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LatestCompanyNotes]
AS

SELECT [CompanyId], [WhenTime], [Notes]
FROM [Meetings] AS M1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT [CompanyId], MAX([Id]) AS [MaxId]
        FROM [Meetings]
        GROUP BY [CompanyId]
    ) AS M2 ON M2.[CompanyId] = M1.[CompanyId] AND M2.[MaxId] = M1.[Id]
```

Now you should be able to join to this view in your query as you've previously done.

```
SELECT Companies.[ID], Companies.[Name], mts.[WhenTime], mts.[Notes]
FROM [Companies]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LatestCompanyNotes] AS mts ON mts.[CompanyId] = Companies.[ID]
ORDER BY Companies.[Name] ASC
```

*Please note that I've not tested the code (I don't even have SQL Server installed) and it may require a few small changes to work.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I went with the other solution because it's smaller and doesn't require the view.

Comment: Re your note at the bottom: You were *very* close (impressive!). I fixed the select in the view (needed an alias for the max(id) and needed to include the company id in the `on` clause). I've tested that select and it works. I've also made the join in the final select explicitly outer.

Comment: @Tominator: Kane's approach doesn't *require* a view, the view just makes it simpler. It also has the advantage of not relying on a SQL Server-specific feature (cross apply).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cross-apply here, just a correlated sub-query to find the most recent meeting date:

```
SELECT Companies.ID, Companies.name, mts.whentime, mts.notes
FROM Companies
LEFT OUTER JOIN Meetings mts
ON Companies.ID = mts.companyID
AND mts.WhenTime =
 (SELECT MAX(WhenTime) FROM Meetings mtshist WHERE mtshist.companyID = mts.companyID)
ORDER BY Companies.name
```

Note that this will retrieve all companies, including those which have never had a meeting:

> ```
> 1 Alexander and co.   2010-01-04 some more notes
> 2 Barnard Partnership 2010-01-03 NULL
> 3 Collingwood Ltd.    2010-01-07 recent meeting
> 4 Dimitri and sons    NULL       NULL
> ```